How to properly use supabase.auth.getSession();
I'm implementing Supabase auth in my Next.js 14 app and I need to use session informations in server requests (informations not available with getUser).
I know that supabase.auth.getSession(); is not fully secure because of the cookie so I figured that supabase.auth.refreshSession(); was the perfect solution.
To avoid calling refreshSession() multiple times in a page load as I need user informations in different components, I tried to set refreshSession() in the middleware replacing the getUser from the Supabase doc.
With that middleware solution, I can safely use getSession() in my components because the session will be refreshed by the middleware.
My problem is that I have the warning in the console
Using supabase.auth.getSession() is potentially insecure as it loads data directly from the storage medium (typically cookies) which may not be authentic. Prefer using supabase.auth.getUser() instead. To suppress this warning call supabase.auth.getUser() before you call supabase.auth.getSession().
Can anyone tell me how to avoid that? Is there a better solution to fulfill my needs?

You get user data with:
const { data: { user } } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

This has replaced the older getSession() calls

This is not a solution because it says that the data required is not available with getUser but only with getSession...

From the Supabase docs: "If you need verified, trustworthy user data, call getUser instead."
